# Bootstrap collapse overlap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 collapse without accordion syntax but when the element expands, there is a conflict with the next one beneath it and they overlap. [See here](http://dev.zimmi.cz/stackoverflow/).
I really appreciate any help as I've been struggling with this for hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#snippet-layersList-
{
  display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Add this in your program. Modyify the above id with specified parameters. It works fine